# Run Page Object Robot Tests on Sauce Labs

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, saucelabs

I have some Robot Framework tests and I would like to run them on sauce Labs.
I use to run tests locally through this command line syntax :

```
pybot -vbaseurl:http://myurl  FunctHomePage.robot
```

As of Now I need to add some sauce labs options to my syntax :

```
pybot -vbaseurl:http://myurl.fr  -v DESIRED_CAPABILITIES:"build:demo,platform:Windows     2008,version:40,browserName:firefox,javascriptEnabled:True" -v REMOTE_URL:http://username:saucekey.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub  FunctHomePage.robot
```

However when running this I face a selenium web driver error

```
WebDriverException: Message: Couldn't connect to webdriver after several attempts
```

In fact selenium is trying to run my tests in phantomJs which is the default browser for Robot Page Object Library whereas I have given firefox as a browser in desired capabilities.

I think there is a conflict in my settings but not sure how to deal with it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that when using Page Object Library, I should use the Library Built in options to Launch tests on sauce Labs here is the complete command line, it works!!

```
 pybot -v browser:firefox -v baseurl:http://myurl -v sauce_apikey:mykey -v sauce_platform:linux -v sauce_username:myusername FunctHomePage.robot
```